# Do classes serialized as Object lose their type information?

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization, casting

I have a serializable `Message` class that has a `Data As Object` property that I'm using as a generic holder for information to be sent via a system that uses a combination of push technology and/or IPC to communicate with any other programs that are interested in the information. This allows the communication piece to be agnostic of the information it transmits.

I was serializing this `Data As Object` as a `Byte[]`, since I was worried about how an `Object` being serialized and transmitted across the network would behave on the other side. However, when deserializing I get errors about being unable to find the assembly for the types stored within my `Data As Object` property, because I'm deserializing in the assembly that contains the `Message` class... not the assembly that contains the type that `Data As Object` originally was. The assembly that contains the description of the information being transmitted exists on both sides (although, I haven't figured out how I'm going to take care of versioning gracefully yet).

Would sending an `Object` directly be a better solution? I was wondering if I'd lose the type information and be unable to cast it back to the type I want at the other end. Perhaps it's not possible to pass a type as an `Object` via another assembly without it knowing about my type?

There's a good chance I'm approaching the problem entirely the wrong way. Alternatives gladly accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: Do serialized objects lose their types?

A: No

> Q: If I cast an object to "object" before I serialize it, have I lost the
>   type?

A: Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Serialization includes the runtime type of the object being serialized, so type information is not lost (which actually makes built-in binary serialization considerably less efficient when serializing known data in a known format).

> I was serializing this Data As Object as a Byte[]...

If you mean that your are pre-serializing your message data into a binary format, prior to serializing your Message object, that is almost certainly unnecessary.

Without more details about your scenario it is difficult to give you more specific advice.